# Laravel 4 - Custom Error Reporting

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4, and loving it so far - but i'm trying to create a custom error handler.

The default error handler is:

```
App::error(function (Exception $exception, $code) {
});
```

Now I would like be able to get the line number, the file, and the error of which the error is occurring in, the problem is everything in $exception seems to be private - and doing a var_dump of it seems to crash my browser as it's so long.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working fine for me:

```
App::error(function (Exception $exception, $code) {

   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump( $exception->getTrace() );
   echo "</pre>";

});
```

Try it, please.